# Restoring corrupted UTF-8 files

Tags: windows, encoding, file-corruption, character-encoding

After my PC broke down I managed to make a backup of the relevant files before reinstalling Windows.

Now that I'm restoring those files and setting the system up I noticed that some of the files got corrupted in the backup and I was wondering if you have any idea on how to restore their original content.

For example, the image below shows a piece of a corrupted file (opened in notepad). I do know (partially) what the content is: the first line is `<?php`.

[image: Corrupted file example]

Do you think there is a way to recover these files?

I have some experience at programming so if I need to write a script I'm happy to do it but I guess I'd need a conversion map.

Comment: What extensions do these files have to start with?

Comment: Actually I lost files of any kind, from plain text to images and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You won't recover your files.
Corruption is not a defined operation that can be reversed with a script.

Strictly technically UTF-8 is not a file format. It is a way of representing so-called code points.

The simplest tool to analyse a files is a hex editor that shows you binary data and ASCII and maybe UTF symbols. I guess that PHP code is largely represented as ASCII. Notepad does not necessarily show all information, for instance no symbols for bytes with a value below 32. Therefore your image of Notepad does not help at all - possible information is hidden.

Your broken computer leads to the question why it broke down. Is the file system dammaged? How did you backup your files?

What file type are you talking about?

Your description of your incident is insufficient to get an idea what might have happened.

Comment: The backup I made was through a live Ubuntu image to an external hard drive. The PC broke, I guess, for a corrupted driver which indeed I don't understand why broke down.. at first it didn't get past the recovery screen and after a few recovery attempts made through Windows repair tools it even corrupted the MBR. So yeah that should be an alarm. I ran a few checks like chkdsk and it found bad sectors but I couldn't manage to fix the boot but I'm ok with it as the problem must have been quite big, so I don't dislike the format. I found out that just some (of any kind) of the files got corrupted

Comment: Also I checked the hex earlier and there are many null bytes.. sadly I have to accept that then. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

This won't actually ***RECOVER*** missing data (I mean.. where would it get it from?), but it WILL give you back all of your text that could be recovered in an easy way.

The "*secret*"?  ... ... "[dramatic-pause]"... ...
**MICROSOFT WORD**. .. wait.. WHAT? .. ***WORD?*** ??

I used to use it to rip command line options from EXE files and all sorts of other stupid nerd tricks.  This feature has been in there since the early Word95 days.

1. First, open word (*the cool kids pull up the Run dialog and type "winword"*).
2. Click `Open` on the left.  Then find the `Browse` button.

[image]

3. Use the file type drop down and change it to "Recover Text from Any File (*.*)" and find your file.  Ignore the errors.. (of COURSE there are errors!)

[image]

For this sample, I opened notepad.exe.

[image]

This text can now be dropped into notepad.exe or even a not-lame text editor.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I had no idea this feature existed in Word! Anyway, no luck for me.. it just shows an empty sheet when I try to load some of the corrupted files like this :(